# how to sort dictionary object based on values in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I m having object like

```html
var data ={ "a":10,"b":12,"c":34,"d":78 }
```

how to sort this dictionary object based on values in javascript

I need output like

```html
data ={"d":78,"c":34,"b":12,"a":10,}
```

Comment: Why use the code snippet feature when there's nothing to run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order of properties in objects in not guaranteed  but you can create array of keys with `Object.keys()` and sort it by values of object.

```js
var data ={ "a":10,"b":12,"c":34,"d":78 }

var result = Object.keys(data).sort(function(a, b) {
  return data[b] - data[a];
})

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `Object.entries` to get an array of `key-value` pairs and then sort by values.

```js
var data ={ "a":10,"b":12,"c":34,"d":78 }
var result = Object.entries(data).sort(([_a, a], [_b, b]) => b - a)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: value for the key is lost here, how to retain the value also for the key?

Comment: @SaurabhSashank obviously I'm too late, but I believe Nenand meant to use Object.values, not Object.keys

Comment: @tnerbusas You can't sort object because an object is unsorted collection of properties, so what we did here instead is sort an array of keys based on values and then you can use that array as an order of properties in some way

Comment: @NenadVracar Ah I see - this is actually helpful for something else I'm currently doing. Thanks for clarifying